# CSV data export to SQL Database with double quote problems

Tags: ssis, import, export, bulk-insert

I am trying to import data from falt files (.CSV) into SQL table. I am able to import them no problem but the data is coming with double quotes. What is the best way of resolving this problem?

Regards,

Comment: Closed as off-topic? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the text delimiter in the flat file reader properties to the double quote.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mixed data, where some are double quoted and others are single, another option would be to load the complete data into a column and have a computed column in the same table that is running a function to strip out the unwanted characters from the source column.  something like this:

create table [xxxx] (
originalcol varchar(50) null,
[$$derived] as replace(originalcol,'"','')
)

Just saying it may be easier doing it in SQL then SSIS